# Matlab printmat

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab. Is there a way to use `printmat` to print 2 words heading?

Example result as followed:

```
 Title One        Title Two         Title Three
        11               22                  33
        22               33                  44
```

Here is the code i currently trying to modify:

```
matA = [ 11 22 33; 22 33 44];
printmat(matA, '' , '' , 'TitleOne TitleTwo TitleThree');
```

I can't seems to add a space in between 'Title' and 'One' where adding the space always result in the following outcome:

```
printmat(matA, '' , '' , 'Title One Title Two Title Three');

     Title              One               Title
        11               22                  33
        22               33                  44
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Matlabs help, `printmat` will not provide what you are seeking. You can use `sprintf` instead.

```
a = [ 11 22 33; 22 33 44];
s = {'Title One' 'Title Two' 'Title Three'};
s1 = sprintf('%12s\t%12s\t%12s\t\n', s{:});
s2 = sprintf('%12d\t%12d\t%12d\n', a);

horzcat(s1,s2)
```

This results in

```
ans =

   Title One       Title Two     Title Three    
          11              22              22
          33              33              44
```

**~edit~**
If the use of `printmat` is preferable (e.g., because it is more flexible) you can work around by using `evalc` and `strrep`. The trick here is to replace the spaces with other symbols (e.g. question marks) in the call to `printmat`, store the output in a string via `evalc`, and then use `strrep` to replace the question marks by spaces. As a nice byproduct, you get the table as a string...

```
a = [ 11 22 33; 22 33 44];
x = evalc('printmat(matA, '''' , ''a b c'' , ''Title?One Title?Two Title?Three'')');

s = strrep(x, '?', ' ')
```

This results in

```
s =


                 Title One    Title Two  Title Three
            a     11.00000     22.00000     33.00000
            b     22.00000     33.00000     44.00000
```

However, the combination of printmat and evalc causes a lot of apostrophes...

Comment: both of the answer works for me, but I think I better stick to this one for standardization reason.

Comment: which method do you think is the best way of storing space character in a file if I wish to store 'Test String' into a file, not 'TestString'?

Comment: The second one is more flexible, because you do not have to define the exact shape of the matrix like in `sprintf`s of the first method. On the other hand, I would expect that the first method might be slightly faster, but this is only important if you are going to write lots of data.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the documentation of `printmat` tells you that

> PRINTMAT(A,NAME,RLAB,CLAB) prints the matrix A with the row labels
>   RLAB and column labels CLAB.  NAME is a string used to name the
>   matrix.  RLAB and CLAB are string variables that contain the row
>   and column labels delimited by spaces.

So spaces in the title are not natively supported.

As a workaround, you can use another separator that "looks like a space", for example, the [unit separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter):

```
printmat (
    matA, '', 'one two', ...
    ['Title' char(31) 'One Title' char(31) 'Two Title' char(31) 'Three']);
```

output:

```
Test = 
           Title One    Title Two  Title Three
    one     11.00000     22.00000     33.00000
    two     22.00000     33.00000     44.00000
```

But as you see, this gets awkward real fast. It will also probably not look right when printed to file or some other output than the Matlab command window (terminal, for instance). You'll have to experiment a bit.

Personally I would just write my own, more general pretty-printer using `cell`s and `sprintf` with specific field-widths in the format string, as suggested by H.Muster (+1).

Comment: this would be the easy method for me to solve the problem. As what you had said, I better stick with H.Muster method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to redefine `printmat` as follows:
What I've done is add a new parameter to the function called `separator`, and you can call the `printmat_v2` function with the separator you want between titles. 
e.g:

```
 printmat_v2 (matA, ' ' , ' ' , 'Title OneL Title TwoL Title Three','L');
```

Code:

```
function [] = printmat_v2(a,name,rlab,clab,separator)
%PRINTMAT Print matrix with labels.
%
%   PRINTMAT(A,NAME,RLAB,CLAB) prints the matrix A with the row labels
%   RLAB and column labels CLAB.  NAME is a string used to name the 
%   matrix.  RLAB and CLAB are string variables that contain the row
%   and column labels delimited by spaces.  For example, the string
%
%       RLAB = 'alpha beta gamma';
%
%   defines 'alpha' as the label for the first row, 'beta' for the
%   second row and 'gamma' for the third row.  RLAB and CLAB must
%   contain the same number of space delimited labels as there are 
%   rows and columns respectively.
%
%   PRINTMAT(A,NAME) prints the matrix A with numerical row and column
%   labels.  PRINTMAT(A) prints the matrix A without a name.
%
%   See also: PRINTSYS.

%   Clay M. Thompson  9-24-90
%   Copyright (c) 1986-93 by the MathWorks, Inc.

error(nargchk(1,5,nargin));

[nrows,ncols] = size(a);

if nargin<2, name = []; end
if nargin==3, error('Wrong number of input arguments.'); end
if nargin<4,
  rlab = []; clab = [];
  for i=1:nrows, rlab = [rlab, '--',int2str(i),'--> ']; end
  for i=1:ncols, clab = [clab, '----',int2str(i),'---- ']; end
  rlab=rlab(1:length(rlab)-1);
  clab=clab(1:length(clab)-1);
end

col_per_scrn=5;
len=12;


if (nrows==0)|(ncols==0), 
  if ~isempty(name), disp(' '), disp([name,' = ']), end
  disp(' ')
  disp('     []')
  disp(' ')
  return
end

% Remove extra spaces (delimiters)
ndx1 = find(clab==separator);
ndx2 = find([ndx1,0]==[-1,ndx1+1]);
if ~isempty(clab), clab(ndx1(ndx2))=[]; end

ndx1 = find(rlab==' ');
ndx2 = find([ndx1,0]==[-1,ndx1+1]);
if ~isempty(rlab), rlab(ndx1(ndx2))=[]; end

% Determine position of delimiters
cpos = find(clab=='L');
if length(cpos)<ncols-1, error('Not enough column labels.'); end
cpos = [0,cpos,length(clab)+1];

rpos = find(rlab==' ');
if length(rpos)<nrows-1, error('Not enough row labels.'); end
rpos = [0,rpos,length(rlab)+1];

col=1;
n = min(col_per_scrn-1,ncols-1);
disp(' ')
if ~isempty(name), disp([name,' = ']), end  % Print name
while col<=ncols
  % Print labels
  s = ' '*ones(1,len+1);
  for j=0:n,
    lab = clab(cpos(col+j)+1:cpos(col+j+1)-1);
    if length(lab)>len,
      lab=lab(1:len);
    else
      lab=[' '*ones(1,len-length(lab)),lab]; end
    s= [s,' ',lab];
  end
  disp(s)
  for i=1:nrows,
    s = rlab(rpos(i)+1:rpos(i+1)-1); 
    if length(s)>len, s=s(1:len); else s=[' '*ones(1,len-length(s)),s]; end
    s = [' ',s];
    for j=0:n,
      element = a(i,col+j);
      if element==0,
        s=[s,'            0'];
      elseif (element>=1.e6)|(element<=-1.e5)|(abs(element)<.0001)
        s=[s,sprintf(' %12.5e',element)];
      else
        s=[s,sprintf(' %12.5f',element)];
      end
    end
    disp(s)
  end % for
  col = col+col_per_scrn;
  disp(' ')
  if (ncols-col<n), n=ncols-col; end;
end % while
```

Comment: Instead of making changes to matlab's core functions, I would rather make copies of the files and save them under (slightly) different names.

Comment: @H.Muster yeah you are rigth. Maybe the name of the function should change a little bit. I'll edit my question.